# Binary XML file line XX: Error inflating class When inherit the BottomSheet

Tags: java, android, xml

Since I began to create the inheritors from Android Views, I frequently see the error `Binary XML file line XX: Error inflating class`. In this special case it will be the `BottomSheet`.

```
public class MyBottomSheet extends TableLayout {

    BottomSheetBehavior myBottomSheetBehavior;
    ImageView testImageView;

    public MyBottomSheet(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        testImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); // still OK...

        myBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(this); // crashes Here
        testImageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener); // or here if to remove the previous row

    }

    // ...
}
```

My app has multiple tabs with individual fragments. The `BottomSheet` requires only in one of them, however if I dont't include the `BottomSheet` in the MainActivity markup, it will not move. So the code is:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- ... -->

        <include layout="@layout/my_bottom_sheet"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**my_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.bottomsheettest.widgets.MyBottomSheet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    tools:context="com.example.bottomsheettest.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
    </TableRow>

</com.example.bottomsheettest.widgets.MyBottomSheet>
```

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_main;
    private MainViewFAB fab;
    private MyBottomSheet addNewItemToInboxBottomSheet;

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        fab = activity.getMainViewFab();

        addNewItemToInboxBottomSheet =  (MyBottomSheet) activity.findViewById(R.id.myBottomSheet);

        return inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

    }
}
```

I supposeI missed something important about Android Views inheritance. But this case especially strange. In the `MyBottomSheet` class, there are no problem when getting the `ImageView` from the `BottomSheet`. Consequently, the access to `BottomSheet` from the respective class is available. However, if try to manipulate somethig related with `BottomSheet`, the exception will be.

---

I share the [source code](https://yadi.sk/d/O-vVpMt33JxgHt) (.zip) created in the Android Studio during accept the some answer. There are no tabs in shared app, however I kept the fragment structure because it exists in the original app.

Comment: Well, the `setOnClickListener()` call on the `ImageView` will crash because it won't have been added to your custom `View` yet in the constructor. You can do that in `onFinishInflate()` instead. What's the error for the `BottomSheetBehavior` crash?

Comment: Oh, actually, I believe that'll crash because your custom `View` won't have its `LayoutParams` set yet in the constructor, and `BottomSheetBehavior.from()` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. You should be able to do that in `onFinishInflate()`, too.

Comment: @Mike M: The error is same in both `BottomSheetBehavior` and `Listener` cases: ` android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31` (yes, same until the row number). I will check the theory about `LayoutParams` and write again.

Comment: @Mike M: if I add  `MyBottomSheet.LayoutParams thisViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams();` in the constructor, which arguments I should to set in `LayoutParams()`? All of them already set in XML, so something like `LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)` will be redundant, isn't it?

Comment: Uh, that's not at all what I suggested. I suggested that you move everything you have in the constructor shown above (except for the `super` call, obviously) to `onFinishInflate()`.

Comment: Now that I think about it, though, you'll probably need to move the `BottomSheetBehavior` initialization to `onAttachedToWindow()` instead.

Comment: @ Mike M, Yes, the Listener part is O'K now! But if about `BottomSheetBehavior` part, even if inside `onAttachedToWindow()`, I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior`.

Comment: Yeah, right, I didn't notice before, but you haven't set the `layout_behavior` on it in the layout XML. All the `from()` method does is grab the behavior that's already been constructed during inflation. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: @Mike M, Oh, I forgot about `behavior_hideable`, `behavior_peekHeight` and `layout_behavior`. Everythig O'K  now thanks to you! Please add the short answer and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Excellent. It'll be a minute before I can put together an answer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a `View` subclass that is meant to be inflated from a layout, there are several things that won't be available in the constructor at runtime.

For one, child `View`s of your custom `View` defined in the layout will not have been inflated and attached yet, so any attempt to get references to them with `findViewById()` will return null there. Instead, this should be done no earlier than `onFinishInflate()`, and moving your `ImageView` initialization to that method will solve that particular error.

Also, your custom `View` itself will not have had its own `LayoutParams` set yet in the constructor. This is causing the issue with the `BottomSheetBehavior.from()` call there, since that method simply retrieves the `Behavior` from the `LayoutParams` constructed during inflation from layout attributes on the `View`. In the `onAttachedToWindow()` method, the `LayoutParams` will have been set, and you can make the `BottomSheetBehavior.from()` call there.

Lastly, I would just mention that an `InflateException` is thrown whenever anything goes wrong with inflation. The root cause of the failure will be listed further on in the stack trace, and you should look there to find the more relevant details.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I was need it for deep understanding.